# Number of points over elliptic curve is p+1 given....

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Suppose that -1 is not a square in $\mathbb{Z_p}$. Show that the number of points on the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax$ over $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is $p+1$.

Hint: Use the fact that $x^3+ax$ is an odd function.

I'm not even too sure where to start. From what I understand about a curve like this, is that if a point $(x,y)$ exists on the curve, then a point $(x,-y)$ also exists. So the curve is reflected in the line $y=0$. Since this is in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, we shouldn't run into any such $y$ where $y=-y$, except when $y-0$. So they way I think about it is that there should be an odd number of points, that is an even number (due to the reflection) plus the one point at $(0,0)$. Although I've been staring at this question so long, that I am now mixing up things and trying to make things so basic...

I've also attepted to work with the fact that $\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)=-1$, but can't relly see how that fits in properly.

Comment: There's also the point at infinity. The way to use the hint is to observe that $x^3+ax$ is a non-zero square in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ if and only if $(-x)^3+a(-x)$ is a non-zero non-square. So you get two $y$:s for one and none for the other.

Comment: Of course, I was forgetting all about the point at infinity. That fits things nicely. Thanks, I think I know where I'm going now.

Answer (score 0):

if x is not equal to zero modulo $p$ we can replace $x$ by $p-x$ in $$x^3 + ax = x(x^2+a).$$

Exactly one of the two different expressions is  quadratic. In one case there are two points on the curve with the given $x$ value, since there are two $y$ values, the square root of $\pm\sqrt{x(x^{2}+a)}$. Without the point $(0,0)$ we get $p-1$ points. If we add $(0,0)$ and the point at infinity we find a total of $p + 1$ points.